# Osmdroid with Fragments - no map displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, osmdroid

i'm trying to run my app with osmdroid (it already worked with Google Maps). But somehow i do not get any map displayed if i use it in my app context. I tryed to change the following things (i only want to display the map at first):

in my `GoogleMapActivity` Class:

changed imports from

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
```

to

```
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
```

and from

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {
```

to

```
public class OSMActivity extends Activity {
```

removed the unused method for Android `isRouteDisplayed()`

in my **Manifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.fragments"
android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="1.02" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="de.fragments.MyApplication">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:name="de.map.GoogleMapActivity"  
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

only removed the uses-library

and in my **map_view** file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/description" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="1234" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

changed the `com.google.android.maps.MapView` to `org.osmdroid.views.MapView` and removed the `apiKey`.

I use the 2 jar Files **osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar** and **slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar**

My Application works, but no route is displayed. Any help?
Thanks in advance.